# Using string templates instead of HTML files

Tags: javascript, dojo

When we create our own widgets in DOJO, we provide a template file to it. And the template file is loaded using `dojo/text` module. The typical structure of the widget goes like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/SomeWidget.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template
    });

});
```

The HTML template looks something like this:

```
<div class="someClass">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: clickAction">
    Sample Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Would it create any difference in terms of performance if we provide `templateString` to the widget directly as string and not load it via `dojo/text` module? Like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/SomeWidget.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: "<div class=\"someClass\"><div data-dojo-attach-point= \"titleNode\" data-dojo-attach-event= \"onclick: clickAction\">Sample Content</div></div>"
    });

});
```

Would this change cause the page to load faster than the previous approach?

Comment: Why don't you try and see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

When using module `dojo/text` to load an HTML file (your template) in your application, a network request is made in order to fetch your HTML file.

So `dojo/text` in developer mode add some network overhead. In this environment it is not really a problem.

But when you ship your application in production you should consider building it.

The dojo build process will automatically include all your HTML files as a string in the layer (a layer is a JS file which could be one output of your build process) you are exporting so all the requests to HTML files are eliminated so their network requests.

Comment: Do we require any extra tools for the building process? Can you provide a sample configuration file for the same? I am unable to understand the doc completely.

Comment: @Himanshu The dojo build could be a little complicate to set up, I suggest you to start from a boilerplate https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate if you have question related to the build process please add a new questions SO community will be glad to help you out

Comment: @Himanshu if you think my answer helped you out, please do not forget to accept it or upvoting using the tick icon and arrow up on its left side. Thanks for your collaboration and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little bit faster with templateString declared to the widget directly as string and not load it via dojo/text module because it doesn't have to load another file.